# symfony2 twig : best pratice for highlighting a navbar when on the right page

Tags: jquery, css, symfony, twig, navbar

On my site I have a navbar with links towards different controllers.
So far I was using jquery to highlight the link of the current page but somehow things gor more complicated and it's not enough anymore.

So my question is : what is the best practice to highlight the current page link on a navbar ?
- pass the id of the link as an argument in the template ?
- something more automatic that wouldn't require modifying every controllers' responses?

Comment: Easiest way is to pass the selected_page_id(s) as a global var to twig. This way u don't need to edit your controllers.

Comment: I'm using [KnpMenuBundle](http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) which does the work for me.

Comment: @DarkBee : can you ellaborate on how you make that work? seems interesting - Alain, the bundle looks nice but does not seem super easy to customize. Thanks!

Comment: @Sebastien, you're right that's a bit tricky to tame at first sight, but if you spend 3-4 hours once, you'll get it forever :-).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming u can match the current page with the ID in your database and you are using a base template for you site. I suggest you could do something like this :

## base.twig.html

```
{% import "somemacros.twig.html" as macros %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
        <title>{{ title | default('') }}</title>

        <!-- ************** Metas ************** -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
          <div id="container">
              <div id="sidebar_left">
              <!-- Just to be lazy -->
                 {{ macros.menu(links) }}
             </div>
              <div id="content">
                   {% block content %}

                   {% endblock %}
              </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## somemacros.twig.html

```
{% macro menu(links, class) %}
    {% if not links is empty %}
        {% for link in links %}
            {% if link['selected'] is defined and link['selected'] %}
                {% set is_selected = true %}
            {% else %}
                {% set is_selected = false %}
            {% endif %} 
            <li{%if class != '' %} class="{{ class }}"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ link.getRoute }}" {% if link.PageId in selected_page_ids or link.hasPublicChildren or is_selected %} class="{% if link.PageId in selected_page_ids or is_selected %}selected{% endif %} {%if link.hasPublicChildren%}dropdown{%endif%}"{% endif %}>{{ link.name }}</a>
                {% if link.hasPublicChildren %}
                    <ul>
                        {{ _self.menu(link.getPublicChildren) }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

## PHP logic

```
<?php
    // ...
    // register twig
    // find out current page / page parents if u are using submenu's
    // ...

   $twig->addGlobal('selected_page_ids', $page_ids); //page_ids is an array of the selected page ids
   // run symfony
```

After adding the variable of the current `$page_id` (or `$page_ids` in my case because I have submenu's) as a global to `twig` you now can access this var everywhere, even inside macros. As you can see in my menu macro I then use `{% if link.PageId in selected_page_ids` to add my selected class. The macro is there because i'm lazy